# Asp.net MVC 2, spark engine and strongly Typed Html Helpers

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, spark-view-engine

Will I get the advantage of the new [Strongly Typed Html Helpers with asp.net MVC 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx) if were to use the [spark engine](http://sparkviewengine.com/) for rendering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use any HtmlHelper that ship with the MVC framework in Spark view engine.

```
${Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Name)}
```

Comment: Spark version 1 did not support strongly typed helpers. But if you want to use mvc2, you got to use newest build of Spark anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Spark view page base class doesn't have public property Html with HtmlHelper type but u can add it yourself.

Add 
`<var Html="new HtmlHelper<YourModel>(base.ViewContext, this)"/>` 
on your spark view and after  that u can use 
`${ Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)}` as well as `${Html.Label("some label")}`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are confused about it, you can't definitely know how to do, you still use aspx-like expression - <%statement%> :) Inline code in Spark supports #statement variation too.

Source: [Spark expressions](http://dev.dejardin.org/documentation/expressions#Inlinecode)